# How to add an UIButton to a MKAnnotation (MKView)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, mapkit, mkmapview

I want to add a click able button to a MKAnnotation as seen in this screenshot of the Maps application:

[Preview http://www.img-hosting.de/bilder/24558PlacemarkWithIconpng](http://www.img-hosting.de/bilder/24558PlacemarkWithIconpng)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UIButton *disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; 
annoView.canShowCallout = YES;    
annoView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosureButton;
```